# Find out how many times ‘Chai’ product has been ordered?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to stackoverflow, I recently went through an interview as developer, and I was asked a question regarding SQL.

Given two table product and orders, how to find a Name of prodcut 'Chai' have been ordered

Comment: please add sample data and desired output.

Comment: If someone orders 2 chai, will that be one or two chai rows in the order table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` on common column as following

```
select
  name,
  coalesce(count(o.*), 0) as total
from product p
join orders o
on p.product_id = o.product_id
where name = 'Chai'
group by
  name
```

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer should clarify what should happen if chai has never been ordered.